# how split list to list of lists by index jump

Tags: python, list

have below list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and want to convert to below:

```
b = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

tried below but result not true

```
b = [i for i in a[::2]]
```

how can do it and what is shortest way?

Comment: `it = iter(a); b = [list(ai) for ai in zip(it, it)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another possible way slightly different to @Mesejo's way suggested in the comment would be:

```
n=2
[a[idx:idx+n] for idx in range(0, len(a), n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array(a).reshape(-1, 2).tolist()
```